# Can't figure out how to get started with powerdns-recursor lua scripting

Tags: scripting, ubuntu-12.04, domain-name-system, lua

I have a server (Ubuntu 12.04) where I run [powerdns-recursor](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/pdns-recursor).

I'm trying to add some logic to certain requests and have got my target set on lua scripting for powerdns.

I don't seem to be able to get it to work though.

I guess/hope that the version of the recursor that is available in the ubuntu repositories has the lua support compiled in. I find it likely that that is the case since liblua5.1-0 is a requirement for the package. Also, when I reload the lua script I seem to get sane output:

```
$ sudo rec_control reload-lua-script
ok, reload/unload queued
```

I've created a lua file and set up my configuration to load it:

```
$ grep lua /etc/powerdns/recursor.conf 
# lua-dns-script    Filename containing an optional 'lua' script that will be used to modify dns answers
lua-dns-script=/etc/powerdns/script.lua
```

I've added one [example](http://wiki.powerdns.com/trac/wiki/Lua) script to the file and reloaded the server.

The example script is:

```
$ cat /etc/powerdns/script.lua 
function preresolve ( ip, destination, domain, qtype )
        if domain == "the.time."
        then
                d=os.date("\"%c\"")
                ret={
                        {qtype="16", ttl=1, place="1", content=d},
                }
                if qtype == pdns.TXT
                then
                        return 0, ret
                else
                        return -1, {}
                end
        end
        return -1, {}
end
function nxdomain ( ip, destination, domain, qtype )
    return -1, {}
end
```

But when I request the 'the.time'-record I don't get the desired result:

```
$ nslookup -type=TXT the.time. 1.2.3.4
Server:     1.2.3.4
Address:    1.2.3.4#53

** server can't find the.time.: NXDOMAIN
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Remove "destination" from the function arguments.

From https://doc.powerdns.com/md/recursor/scripting/, preresolve() takes only three arguments

> preresolve ( remoteip, domain, qtype )

Comment: Thank you Jemshad!

Since it has been almost a year since I asked the question I unfortunately don't possess the environment I used to, so it is hard for me to verify your answer.